# Groovier way of manipulating the list

Tags: groovy

I have two list like this :

```
def a = [100,200,300]
def b = [30,60,90]
```

I want the Groovier way of manipulating the `a` like this :

1) First element of `a` should be changed to `a[0]-2*b[0]`

2)Second element of `a` should be changed to `a[1]-4*b[1]`

3)Third element of `a` should be changed to `a[2]-8*b[2]`

(provided that both `a` and `b` will be of same length of `3`)

If the list changed to `map` like this, lets say:

```
def a1 = [100:30, 200:60, 300:90]
```

how one could do the same above operation in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using collect

In response to Victor in the comments, you can do this using a collect

```
def a = [100,200,300]
def b = [30,60,90]

// Introduce a list `c` of the multiplier
def c = (1..a.size()).collect { 2**it }

// Transpose these lists together, and calculate
[a,b,c].transpose().collect { x, y, z ->
  x - y * z
}
```

#### Using inject

You can also use `inject`, passing in a map of multiplier and result, then fetching the result out at the end:

```
def result = [a,b].transpose().inject( [ mult:2, result:[] ] ) { acc, vals ->
  acc.result << vals.with { av, bv -> av - ( acc.mult * bv ) }
  acc.mult *= 2
  acc
}.result
```

And similarly, you can use inject for the map:

```
def result = a1.inject( [ mult:2, result:[] ] ) { acc, key, val ->
  acc.result << key - ( acc.mult * val )
  acc.mult *= 2
  acc
}.result
```

Using `inject` has the advantage that you don't need external variables declared, but has the disadvantage of being harder to read the code (and as Victor points out in the comments, this makes static analysis of the code hard to impossible for IDEs and groovypp)

Comment: +1 to last line - that's a harder way to maintain state over loop, plus it's untyped.

Comment: Why does untyped matter in this context?

Comment: As for me, I use Groovy++ and IntelliJ IDEA that infers types and does a good job on static analysis, so typing matters for me. Er, I believe there is no context here to speak of, so let's consider all possibilities.

Comment: @VictorSergienko thought of a method using collect that is more type friendly ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For `List`, I'd go with:

```
def result = []
a.eachWithIndex{ item, index ->
  result << item - ((2**index) * b[index])
}
```

For `Map` it's a bit easier, but still requires an external state:

```
int i = 1
def result = a.collect { k, v -> k - ((2**i++) * v) }
```

A pity, Groovy doesn't have an analog for [`zip`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zip_f.html), in this case - something like `zipWithIndex` or `collectWithIndex`.

Comment: It calls the closure with two variables the element, and the index in the list.  There's various loops [discussed here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-looping-in-different.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
def a1 = [100:30, 200:60, 300:90]

a1.eachWithIndex{item,index ->
println item.key-((2**(index+1))*item.value)
i++
}
```